# Creating a sphere from a rounded cube is causing ridges

Tags: mirror

I'm hoping you can help me with a basic issue that seems to have me stumped!

I've been trying to create a sphere from a rounded cube but I've had a problem with it not joining correctly and I'm having issues with it creating a harsh ridge around the x and y-axis. (Second picture should show this)

I'm following a tutorial where you place a rounded cube, pop the radius at 1, pop the object in edit mode and delete half of the verticies (pictured below)

[image: Picture 1]

I'm then adding a mirror modifier, and ticking the "Clipping" box, and then adding another subdivison surface modifier of 2. The tutorial I'm following has a perfectly spherical appearance but mine has these harsh ridges.

[image]

I thought adding "Shade smooth" on object mode might help but it has worsened my problem.

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated :) Here is the tutorial I am following if it helps explain my problem at all. https://youtu.be/rEBwBrRzyhw?t=180

Many thanks,
Ali

Comment: You say you add **another** subdivision surface modifier after the mirror. You shouldn't have any s.s. modifiers before mirroring. Make sure the all s.s. modifiers are after (below) the mirror modifier.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Apologies, I meant to say adding another "modifier". I've tried swapping the order of these modifiers around but nope, my sphere is still very ridgy! I'm still looking like a chuppachup lolly : )

Comment: do you have inner faces?

Comment: @moonboots Yes I believe so : )

Comment: So this is the problem I guess

Comment: @moonboots Sorry to sound daft but I believe in the tutorial, the lady only deletes the vertices of one half of the rounded cube (before mirroring). She doesn't seem to have this issue with the ridges or the inner faces? I'm still struggling to get my head around what to do to get that smooth finish.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... if you have inner faces it won't work properly as it will try to interpolate the shade between outer and inner faces

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/2795217bf8104d918ee9898c3348bbfd

Makes a lot of sense about it struggling with the inner/outer interpolation - is there a way I can make it only mirror the outer faces? Thanks in advance @moonboots :)

Comment: actually you didn't have inner face, you had overlapping vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices as you can see here (I had to disable the *Proportional Editing* option as it would move the other vertex):

[image]

It creates a face that stick to the mirror axis, thus the artefacts. So select all and *Merge by Distance* to remove all unwanted vertices.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure how I ended up with overlapping vertices but I'd have never figured this out alone. Thank you :) xx

Comment: you probably extruded with E then Enter, so you weren't able to see the extrusion