# Why do my rounded cubes have overlapping vertices?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices, subdivision-surface

I tried following a tutorial that starts off with using a rounded cube to create a sphere.
here's the vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEBwBrRzyhw

There has been a question with the same problem, but the answer doesn't help me fully.
here's the question: [Creating a sphere from a rounded cube is causing ridges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218161/creating-a-sphere-from-a-rounded-cube-is-causing-ridges)

When I add a rounded cube and set the radius to 1, the round cube already has overlapping vertices all along the middle, which causes ridges when I mirror and subdivide the shape like in the tutorial. In the video, the person does not encounter this problem and apparently no commenters do either, so I'm assuming there's something wrong with how my rounded cubes spawn? But why and how do i fix it?

I do know how to get around this problem by using a default cube, but I wonder if there is something wrong with, for example, how my blender is set up.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry, are you sure the rounded cube has overlapping vertices? Are they there before you add a _Mirror_ and _Subdivision Surface_ modifier? After creating a rounded cube - without any modifiers - go to _Edit Mode_, select all with A and then press M > _Merge_ > _By Distance_. In the status bar below the viewport it should say "Removed 0 vertice(s)" or is there a number > 0? Usually there should be no overlapping geometry right from the start and I only get the ridge if I mirror and subdivide without deleting one half of the cube - which you do not mention in your workflow, by the way.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann, thanks for the comment. I should have stated that more concretely i suppose, but yes, I am sure the rounded cube has overlapping vertices. if I spawn a rounded cube with a radius <1, it's fine. When the radius gets to 1, for some reason the cube gets created with overlapping vertices down the y and x axis

Comment: Could you upload a file with a rounded cube after spawning? You can do this here https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question.